# How can I parse specified fields from given txt query

Tags: c++

C++ question:

I have the query in txt like this:

```
CUSTOMER_ID=4155&ORDER_ITEM_TYPE_ID=1&ORDER_ITEM_TYPE_NAME=Product&ORDER_ITEM_SKU=&ORDER_CURRENCY_CODE=UAH
```

How can I get these fields to make it look nearly like:

```
Customer_ID: 4155
ORDER_ITEM_TYPE_ID: 1
// and etc...
```

I know there is a separator "&" between each field, but I don't know how to do it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use methods of `std::string` like `find`,`substr`. Example:

```
   const std::string field = "CUSTOMER_ID=4155&ORDER_ITEM_TYPE_ID=1&ORDER_ITEM_TYPE_NAME=Product&ORDER_ITEM_SKU=&ORDER_CURRENCY_CODE=UAH";
   const char separator = '&';
   const char equal = '=';

   std::string::size_type cur = 0;
   while ( cur != std::string::npos )
   {
        std::string name;
        std::string value;

        std::string::size_type newPos = field.find(equal, cur);
        if ( newPos != std::string::npos )
        {
             name = field.substr( cur, newPos - cur );
             cur = newPos + 1;

             newPos = field.find(separator, cur);

             value = field.substr( cur, ( newPos == std::string::npos ) ? std::string::npos : newPos - cur );
             cur = ( newPos == std::string::npos ) ? std::string::npos : newPos + 1;

             std::cout << name << ": " << value << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
             break;
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
`char str[10][20];
int len = 0;
int count = 0;
while((c = string[i])!= EOC )
/* EOC : End of Character */
{
    if (c == '&') {
         str[count][len] = '\0';
         len = 0;
         count++;
         continue;
     }
    str[count][len] = c;
     len++;
}
```

Comment: This solution is not nice c++. It's just a old c solution for this problem

Answer (score 0):

Replace all '&' with replace and then when you write the data after this back into a file it's formated as requested.

```
std::ifstream infile("thefile.txt");
while (std::getline(infile, line)) //Read File line by line
{
std::replace( line.begin(), line.end(), '&', '\0'); // replace all '&' to '\0'
cout << line << endl;
}
```